# Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, heatmap

I've been searching around but couldn't find an easy solution to plot two heatmaps in one graphic by having each square in the heatmap split into two triangles (similar to the attached graphic I saw in a paper). Does anybody know a Python package that is able to do this? I tried seaborn but I don't think it has an easy way to achieve this.

[image]

Thank you for your time!

-Peter

Comment: doesn't this defeat the purpose of a heatmap? can you find the hotspots?

Comment: @RichieV Basically, I want to see hotspots related to two different properties. Instead of needing to find the same square in two separate plots I want to have it in the same graph (similar to the image I attached).

Comment: I know what the plot says, my comment was that a heatmap is commonly used to quickly see hot regions... and that combined version makes it quite difficult to spot them at a glance

Comment: I would personally prefer to calculate a combined indicator and do a regular heatmap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`plt.tripcolor` colors a mesh of triangles similar to how `plt.pcolormesh` colors a rectangular mesh. Also similar to `pcolormesh`, care has to be taken that there is one row and one column of vertices less than there are triangles. Furthermore, the arrays need to be made 1D (`np.ravel`). All this renumbering to 1D can be a bit tricky.

As an example, the code below creates a coloring depending on `x*y mod 10` and uses two different colormaps for the upper and the lower triangles.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation

M = 30
N = 20
x = np.arange(M + 1)
y = np.arange(N + 1)
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = (xs * ys) % 10
zs = zs[:-1, :-1].ravel()

triangles1 = [(i + j*(M+1), i+1 + j*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
triangles2 = [(i+1 + j*(M+1), i+1 + (j+1)*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
triang1 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles1)
triang2 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles2)
img1 = plt.tripcolor(triang1, zs, cmap=plt.get_cmap('inferno', 10), vmax=10)
img2 = plt.tripcolor(triang2, zs, cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis', 10), vmax=10)

plt.colorbar(img2, ticks=range(10), pad=-0.05)
plt.colorbar(img1, ticks=range(10))
plt.xlim(x[0], x[-1])
plt.ylim(y[0], y[-1])
plt.xticks(x, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: to have the integer ticks nicely in the center of the cells (instead of at their borders), following changes would be needed:

```py
triang1 = Triangulation(xs.ravel()-0.5, ys.ravel()-0.5, triangles1)
triang2 = Triangulation(xs.ravel()-0.5, ys.ravel()-0.5, triangles2)

# ...
plt.xlim(x[0]-0.5, x[-1]-0.5)
plt.ylim(y[0]-0.5, y[-1]-0.5)
plt.xticks(x[:-1], rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y[:-1])
```

Comment: Yes, this looks great! However, I am a little bit confused about how to use this. So, I have two separate (square) data arrays (one for each 2D map). How would that relate to xs, ys, zs? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You would need `img1 = plt.tripcolor(triang1, data_array_1.ravel(), cmap=...)` and `img2 = plt.tripcolor(triang2, data_array_2.ravel(), cmap=...)`.   `np.ravel()` changes 2D (or nD) arrays to 1D. The demo code uses `zs` twice to create a verifiable test.

Comment: That works amazingly - thanks so much! 
Just a very minor correction for your PS part of your answer. Add two lines:
plt.xticks(x[:-1], rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y[:-1])