# How to superimpose two heatmap plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize correlations using a heatmap in matplotlib (1.4.3), which works fine. I'd like to highlight specific cells/points in the heatmap, and my first guess was to overlay a second plot that creates the highlights. As `imshow` creates a new window, this does not work as intended, though. A condensed version of my code is below. Is there another way to render something matrix-like on top of an existing figure?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
corrmatrix = df.corr()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(corrmatrix, cmap='afmhot', interpolation='none')

plt.colorbar(im)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.columns)

relevant_cells = df > 0.9
rel_ax = ax.imshow(relevant_cells, cmap='YlOrBr', interpolation='none')

plt.show()
```

Comment: See [plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles) about displaying two heatmaps simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this! My specific problem is solved by the answer below, but this will come in handy when looking at different associations of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emphasis can be achieved by overlaying the two heatmaps and adjusting them by transparency. The color map has been intentionally changed for clarity: if C,C and A,C is True

```
rel_ax = ax.imshow(relevant_cells, cmap='Blues', interpolation='none', alpha=0.7)
```

[image]