# Use matplotlib to plot a heat map with split diagonal

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

I would like to use matplotlib to make a heat map that simultaneously represent two symmetric matrices, say A and B, so that the squares above the diagonal will be colored according to the elements in A, and the squares below the diagonal will be colored according to the elements in B.

There are two things that I do not know how to do:

1. The squares in the diagonal should be split across the diagonal line so that the upper triangles are colored according to the diagonal elements in A, and the lower triangles are colored according to the diagonal elements in B.  How can this be done?
2. Two separate color maps should be used for A and for B, because the ranges of the values in A and B are disparate.  How can two color maps be applied to the same heat map?  A related question is how to place two corresponding color bars, one on the right of the heat map for A and one on the bottom for B.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: An idea is to plot the bars/squares one-by-one separately with different scale and attach the colorbars  manually.

Comment: See also [Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement,followed this [Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles) and tried to modify it according to my need.

In my code below my x-axis should be the list of SOMA values and y-axis should be the list of Q values. QPrecision and Precision are my two values varying which I am representing in the two triangles of cell. The location of the colorbars can be modified by changing the location attribute to 'bottom' or 'top'.
One thing I noticed was PyCharm was not able to display the figure correctly but the saved image looks as the attached Image

```html
M = len(SOMA)
N = len(Q)
x = np.arange(M + 1)
y = np.arange(N + 1)

xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zs1 = result['PRECISION']
zs2 = result['QPRECISION']
zs1 = zs1.astype(dtype=float)
zs2 = zs2.astype(dtype=float)



triangles1 = [(i + j*(M+1), i+1 + j*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
triangles2 = [(i+1 + j*(M+1), i+1 + (j+1)*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
print(np.shape(triangles1))
print(np.shape(triangles2))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

triang1 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles1)
triang2 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles2)

newcmp = ListedColormap(['#DAFFAC','#8FFD03'])

img1 = ax.tripcolor(triang1, zs1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues'))
img2 = ax.tripcolor(triang2, zs2, cmap=plt.get_cmap(newcmp))


  
cb1 = plt.colorbar(img2, ax=[ax], ticks=[5, 4] , location='left',label='Q based Precision', pad=0.15)
cb2 = plt.colorbar(img1, ax=[ax], ticks=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],location='right',label='Suppported Precision', pad =0.05)
   
   
labels = np.arange(4, int(5) + 1, 1)
cb1.set_ticks([4.25, 4.75])
cb1.set_ticklabels(labels)

for tick in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_horizontalalignment("center")


plt.xlim(x[0], x[-1])
plt.ylim(y[0], y[-1])
plt.xlabel("SOMA")
plt.ylabel("Q")

x = np.arange(0.5,22,1) #range of SOMA
y = np.arange(0.5,14,1) #range of Q

plt.xticks(x, SOMA, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y, Q)
plt.title(PLOT_TITLE)
plt.savefig('fig.png',bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

[Sample Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h38Zb.png)