# Colorbar is needed when using Tripcolor to make two-triangle heatmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to do a two-triangle heatmap graph similar with the answer [Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles) provided by JohanC.

My dataset are often NaN type, and if I remove `plt.colorbar(img2,pad=0.05)`, the `dataset` will not be plotted. I guess it is due to NaN values, but is there a better way of plotting it? I tried NoneType and it seems more errors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation

dataset=[-0.1674, -0.988, -0.8619, 0.25882, 0.4415, 0.619, 0.743, 0.868, float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.6962, -0.5693, -0.4465, -0.2707, 0.9088, 0.031, 0.158, 0.334, 0.487, 0.6667, float('nan'), -0.09, -0.9057, 0.27003, -0.6042, 0.521, 0.695, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.545, -0.359, -0.2396, 0.8842, 0.057, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.9534, -0.8257, 0.35309, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.658, -0.53, -0.3522, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.17, -0.9908, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.626, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan')]
dataset = np.array(dataset) # this has no effect
M = 9
N = 9
x = np.arange(M + 1)
y = np.arange(N + 1)
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs=(xs * ys)[:-1, :-1].ravel()
triangles1 = [(i + j*(M+1), i+1 + j*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
triangles2 = [(i+1 + j*(M+1), i+1 + (j+1)*(M+1), i + (j+1)*(M+1)) for j in range(N) for i in range(M)]
triang1 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles1)
triang2 = Triangulation(xs.ravel(), ys.ravel(), triangles2)

img1=plt.tripcolor(triang1, zs, cmap=plt.get_cmap('inferno', 10)) # left-bottom part triangle
img2=plt.tripcolor(triang2, dataset, cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis', 10)) # top-right part triangle
plt.colorbar(img1,)
plt.colorbar(img2,pad=0.05)
plt.show()
```

In addition, it seems difficult to set colorbars for subplots. Is it possible (Or is there a way) to plot the `dataset2` without setting a colorbar?

```
dataset2={}
dataset2[0]=np.array([float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 0.7679, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.8276, float('nan'), -0.86851, -0.0021, -0.325431, float('nan'), 0.63345, -0.7858, -0.5043, -0.8269, -0.1499, -0.8686, -0.002, -0.32487, 0.76769, 0.63383, -0.7857, -0.5044, -0.8279, -0.1499, -0.86847, -0.00239, -0.32511, -0.23228, float('nan'), -0.7856, -0.5044, -0.8277, -0.15025, -0.86866, -0.00226, 0.67467, -0.23244, 0.6339, -0.7856, -0.5045, -0.8277, -0.1498, -0.86839, 0.99792, 0.67468, float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.7856, -0.50427, -0.8274, -0.14969, -0.86834, 0.99772, 0.67494, float('nan'), float('nan')])
dataset2[1]=np.array([float('nan'), float('nan'), -1.486, float('nan'), -1.528, float('nan'), -1.984, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -1.622, -1.341, -1.474, -1.797, -1.705, -1.838, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -1.643, -1.363, -1.496, -1.819, -0.7272, -1.86, float('nan'), float('nan'), -1.343, -0.6665, -0.3857, -0.519, -0.8414, -0.7491, -0.8826, -0.1157, -0.8341, -0.1572, -0.479, -0.1983, -0.3313, -0.6547, -0.5621, -0.6959, -0.9285, -0.6473, -0.9697, -0.2928, -0.0113, -0.1453, -0.4675, -0.375, -0.5092, -0.9508, -0.6692, -0.9926, -0.3153, -0.0332, -0.1674, -0.4897, -0.3974, -0.5315, -0.9724, -0.6915, -0.0141, -0.3363, -0.0557, -0.1893, -0.5121, float('nan'), -0.5531609, -0.7856, -0.50427, -0.8274, -0.14969, -0.86834, 0.99772, 0.67494, float('nan'), float('nan')])
dataset2[2]=np.array([-0.7855, -0.5044, -0.82792, -0.14973, -0.868302, -0.0023, 0.67481, -0.23249, float('nan'), -0.7861, -0.5045, -0.82722, -0.149922, 0.1308, 0.99803, 0.67487, float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.7859, -0.5048, -0.8271, -0.14944, float('nan'), -0.00166, float('nan'), 0.76751, 0.63401, -0.7862, -0.5047, -0.8276, -0.14983, 0.13105, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.7861, -0.5045, -0.8271, -0.14968, -0.86882, 0.99801, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.7854, -0.5041, -0.8268, -0.14989, -0.868442, 0.998, float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), -0.7862, -0.5051, -0.8275, -0.14973, -0.86902, 0.99769, float('nan'), 0.76731, float('nan'), -0.7862, -0.5046, -0.827, -0.1494, -0.86871, 0.99827, 0.67519, 0.76809, float('nan'), -0.7856, -0.50427, -0.8274, -0.14969, -0.86834, 0.99772, 0.67494, float('nan'), float('nan')])
fig,axs=plt.subplots(1,3)
for x in range(3):
        axs[x].tripcolor(triang1, zs, cmap=plt.get_cmap('YlGnBu_r', 10)) 
        axs[x].tripcolor(triang2, dataset2[x], cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis', 10)) 
        axs[x].set_xlim(0,9)
        axs[x].set_ylim(0,9)
plt.show()
```

Finally, I used to plotting graphs by Seaborn, is there a way of plotting two-triangle heatmap by Seaborn?

Comment: It looks like `tripcolor` has some problems with NaNs. Using `np.nanmin()` seems to solve this: `img2 = plt.tripcolor(triang2, dataset, cmap='viridis', vmin=np.nanmin(dataset), vmax=np.nanmax(dataset))` also without the colorbar.   Seaborn doesn't do triangle heatmaps.