# My seaborn colorbar overlaps my heatmap and I can't move it

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heatmap which displays two distinct sets of data and thus requires two separate colorbars. This all works beautifully and looks great apart from the fact that the Blues colorbar overlaps the heatmap. I just need to shift it slightly further left but cannot work out how to.

Code for heatmap is below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize = (8,9))

sb.heatmap(data = df1, linewidth = 0.0, vmin=0, cmap = 'Blues', 
           cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec = False, location = "left"), robust = False)
sb.heatmap(data = df2, linewidth = 0.0, vmin=0,  cmap = 'Reds', robust = False)

cbar1 = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar2 = ax.collections[1].colorbar

plt.show()
```

This then spits out the heatmap below and, as you can see, the blues colorbar is overlapping the heatmap.

[image: Heatmap with overlapping colorbar]

Comment: Hi @Chris - It might be df2 (red plot) is on top of df1(blue plot). Please interchange the two lines and see. I think you will see all blues.... Is that what you are expecting? Or are you expecting to see two plots, one next to another?

Comment: Maybe you want `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncol=2)`? With `sns.heatmap(..., cmap='blues', ax=ax1)` and `sns.heatmap(..., cmap='reds', ax=ax2)`?  Note the colorbars are drawn by `sns.heatmap`, and that `cbar1 = ax.collections[0].colorbar` is just a dummy statement here.

Comment: Note that if you want to show both a blue and a red heatmap, you would need two subplots. Or the red heatmap would need some "holes" (via masking) to let the blue show through. Or you would need something like [splitting into triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles/63531813#63531813).  Either way, more explanation and reproducible test data are needed for your question.

Comment: Thank you to @Redox who understood and provided the answer. It was simply a matter of switching the two lines and it worked. In answer to JohanC , there are two subplots and both colours do appear on the same graph overlapping. There is no need for gaps as the data from both groups cannot overlap. For some reason the blue didn't appear on this one. Thanks all.

Comment: Do the two lines with `cbar1` and `cbar2` have any bearing on this question? If not, I suggest [removing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72910809/edit) them (but ******* ***without*** ********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the two lines detailing the heatmap plots (starting with `sb.heatmap`) fixed it.